# Custom Map Callout Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I have to create custom `MKMapView` annotations, which look almost the same as the ones iOS provides, but have different color (white) and slightly different shape.

My first attempt was to prevent opening the original black `UIAnnotationView`s and in `AnnotationView`'s `setSelected:animated:` added a new subview to the same `UIAnnotationView`. I have animated this view after adding it to the superview. This had only one problem: my custom button in the annotation was not clickable.

After this I've found this excellent example:

https://github.com/tochi/custom-callout-sample-for-iOS

This adds a new `CalloutAnnotation` to the map when the user clicks on a `PinAnnotation`. `PinAnnotation`s have no `AnnotationView`s, only `CalloutAnnotation`s do.

This works fine, except that I can't figure out how to do the iOS-like initial zooming animation on the annotation views when they are created.

The animation I want to use is the following (found here on SO and worked fine with my first attempt):

```
- (void)animateCalloutAppearance:(CalloutAnnotationView *)annotaitonView
{
    self.endFrame = annotaitonView.frame;
    CGFloat scale = 0.001f;
    annotaitonView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, [self xTransformForScale:scale andAnnotation:annotaitonView], [self yTransformForScale:scale]);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.075f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        CGFloat scale = 1.2f;
        annotaitonView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, [self xTransformForScale:scale andAnnotation:annotaitonView], [self yTransformForScale:scale]);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            CGFloat scale = 0.90;
            annotaitonView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, [self xTransformForScale:scale andAnnotation:annotaitonView], [self yTransformForScale:scale]);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.075 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                CGFloat scale = 1.0;
                annotaitonView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, [self xTransformForScale:scale andAnnotation:annotaitonView], [self yTransformForScale:scale]);
            } completion:nil];
        }];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - The helper methods

- (CGFloat)relativeParentXPosition:(CalloutAnnotationView *)annotationView {
    return annotationView.bounds.size.width / 2.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)xTransformForScale:(CGFloat)scale andAnnotation:(CalloutAnnotationView *)annotationView {
    CGFloat xDistanceFromCenterToParent = self.endFrame.size.width / 2.0f - [self relativeParentXPosition:annotationView];
    CGFloat transformX = (xDistanceFromCenterToParent * scale) - xDistanceFromCenterToParent;

    return transformX;
}

- (CGFloat)yTransformForScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    CGFloat yDistanceFromCenterToParent = self.endFrame.size.height / 2.0f;
    CGFloat transformY = yDistanceFromCenterToParent - yDistanceFromCenterToParent * scale;

    return transformY;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer on this blog: http://blog.asynchrony.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

The tricky part is that you have to do the animation in the `CalloutAnnotationView`'s `didMoveToSuperView` :)

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [self animateCalloutAppearance:self];
}
```

I hope it helps somebody else :)

Comment: It sure did :-). I change the scales, timing and alpha. Made it even smoother.